# How to scroll SingleChildScrollView programmatically?

Tags: uiscrollview, flutter

How to scroll [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) programmatically?

On long Form, it is desirable to automatically scroll to a require input field.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are multiple solutions :

- Using `ScrollController`: Assign it to `controller` field of your `SingleChildScrollView`. And use `myScrollController.animateTo` or `myScrollController.jumpTo`
- Use static methods of `Scrollable`. Possibly `Scrollable.ensureVisible`. But be aware that the `context` parameter is the context of the widget that needs to be visible. You can get that context by using `GlobalKey`.

Answer (score 27):

Use `ScrollController` to scroll inside `Column` or `ListView`

Examples:

**Colum With SingleChildScrollView**

```
 class ScrollContainerPage extends StatelessWidget {
      ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('ScrollView Example'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                   /// Scroll maximum end, if you want you can give hardcoded values also in place of _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent
                    _scrollController.animateTo(
                        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        curve: Curves.ease);
                  },
                  child: Text('Scroll To Bottom'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.red,),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue,),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green,),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.yellow,),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**ListView**

```
class ScrollContainerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ScrollView Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _scrollController.animateTo(
                  _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  curve: Curves.ease);
            },
            child: Text('Scroll To Bottom'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.red,),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue,),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green,),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.yellow,),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** Only thing need to make sure that `ScrollController` assigned to respective widget